# Solving $\frac{x + 2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}}}=12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is my attempt:
$$\frac{x + 2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}}}=12$$
$$\implies\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}}=\frac{x+2}{12}$$
$$\implies 1-\frac{3}{x}=\frac{x^{2}+4x+4}{144}$$
$$\implies -\frac{3}{x}=\frac{x^{2}+4x-140}{144}$$
$$\implies x^{3}+4x^{2}-140x+432=0$$
I don't know how to proceed further, so I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Rational Zeroes Theorem -- one of the roots is a factor of $ \ 432 \ = \ 3 \ \cdot \ 144 \ = \ 3 \ \cdot \ 12^2 \ $ .  (It turns out to be a small integer.)

Comment: Minor comment- the "rational zeroes theorem" (I would have said "rational roots theorem") says that **if** a root is rational then it must evenly divide 432.  It does **not** say that there **is** such a root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it help to notice using [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) that $4$ is a root of your polynomial?

Comment: Yes. Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

By inspection we find $4$ as a solution, so you can factor the polynomial on the LHS, from the Factor Theorem, as follows:

\begin{align*}
x^{3}+4x^{2}-140x+432&=(x-4)(x^2+8x-108)
\end{align*}

Now, by the quadratic formula we get two roots for the LHS of your equation:
$$-4\pm2\sqrt{31}$$
Then, you must test with these numbers in the former equation.

Answer (score 1):

If every solution is irrational, you need the formula for cubic equations. This formula is not very useful. So let's try to find rational roots.

Note that the polynomial you obtained is monic, that is, its main coefficient is $1$. This means that every rational root is actually an integer.

Now let's see the radical:
$$\sqrt{1-\frac3x}=\sqrt{\frac{x-3}x}$$

The fraction is in its lowest terms or can be simplified dividing by $3$. Assuming that the radical is rational, the first possibility gives $x=4$, and the second, $x=3$.

$x=4$ is a solution.